# Using vmware fusion on one account while fast user switching

Tags: user-account, vmware

I want to create a standard mac user called vmware to run multiple VMs. If I fast user switch, will those VMs become suspended or inaccessible?

I don't want to use the VMs from my user account, but I'd like to at least SSH into it using Terminal.

My goal is to run WebDAV in a VM and still be able to access files from my iPhone, iPad, or macs even though I'm logged in on another account on the mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the VMs will run fine, I just tested it on my OS X Server. 
All the Services remain running, including the VMWare Fusion Virtual Machines and SSH-Connections.